# Show hours in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I was wondering if anyone could help me with showing this result on entering the number in the input? I have written this code but it is showing errors and not updating the result.

```
let principle = $("#principle").val();
  let interest = $("#interest-rate").val();
  let interest2 = $("#interest-rate-two").val();
  let result = $(".result");
  let inputs = $('input, select');

function update() {
    var val =  principle * interest * interest2;
    result.html( val.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, '$1,'));
  };

  function updateNumber() {
      update();
      inputs.on('change keyup', update);
  };

  updateNumber();
```

https://codepen.io/John_098/pen/BapVQjp

Comment: Consider converting the values from strings into numbers _before_ using maths? `principle * interest * interest2` could result in `NaN`

Comment: *"it is showing errors"* Those error messages are important so always include what they are. Note that you don't want to get values until the function is called. Otherwise they don't reflect changes by user

Comment: The codepen linked does not throw any errors.

Comment: Your codepen link is not throwing any errors...other than NaN issue